# What does "message of over a gigabyte was predicted in tcpros" mean?

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While streaming with theora image_transport, I receive the following error:

*a message of over a gigabyte was predicted in tcpros. that seems highly unlikely, so I'll assume protocol synchronization is lost.*

What might cause this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10296/what-does-%22message-of-over-a-gigabyte-was-predicted-in-tcpros%22-mean?/) by [miltos](https://answers.ros.org/users/559/miltos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kingsimba0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/72936/kingsimba0511/) on 2021-10-28**:
In my case, I think it's the compiler's bug or some bug in roscpp.
I created a very simple program, and the problem still exists. https://github.com/AutoxingTech/simple_publisher_crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error message indicates, it means that the connection some how became out-of-sync.  This could potentially happen if streaming between multiple computers and somehow the libraries are not the same, or something even more esoteric.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2014-10-07**:
I have the same error. In my case, it happens when a node call a service and the server dies.